# Calculate Total of a column in interactive grid for "large numbers"

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid with an "Bedrag" column. I want to sum the total of this column and store it in a page item.

The column "Bedrag" is of type 'Number' and has a format mask : 999G999G999G999G990D00

The page item "Total" is of type 'Number' and also has a format mask : 999G999G999G999G990D00

I am writing the below code in the dynamic action :

```
 var model = apex.region("myStaticIgId").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").model; // myStaticIgId is the region id of IG
 var n_amount, n_total = 0;
 var col_amount = model.getFieldKey("LINE_AMOUNT");
 model.forEach(function(igrow)
   {
           
           n_amount = parseFloat(igrow[col_amount], 10);
           if (!isNaN(n_amount)) {
                     n_total += n_amount;
      }
 }
  );
 
 console.log(n_total);

 $s('P3_TOTAL_LINE_AMOUNT', n_total);
```

This works fine as long as the numbers to be added are less than 1000.

[image]

But if we change the numbers to 1245, 1000. Then it gives a weird result.

[image]

How can I get rid of this problem for numbers greater than or equal to 1000. For smaller numbers it works just fine.

Comment: Voted to re-open, this is a legit question not related to oracle formatting mask but to apex functionality